# how to redirect to 2nd tab in a process

Tags: jquery, html

commerce site i want customer to redirect to 2nd tab of the process step

here is the url for reference: http://tinyurl.com/pnd3udu

I want to redirect to "Your Order & Payment" tab i used #/#order_review after url but not working

here is my js  code:

```
if (res.status == 'ok') {
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                alert(res.message);
            }
```

my question what should i add after window location.reload to directly go to the second tab?

edit-

```
<ul class="clearfix" id="shippingsteps">
   <li class="first">
  <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  <span>1</span><a href="#">
    Checkout Method        </a></li> 
   <li class="first">
  <div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  <span>1</span><a id="billing_tab" data-target="billing_shipping" href="#">
    Billing &amp; Shipping        </a></li>
  <li class="active"><div class="nav-arrow"></div>
  <span>2</span><a id="order_review_tab" data-target="order_review" href="#">
    Your Order &amp; Payment        </a></li>
  <li><span>3</span><a href="#">
    Confirmation        </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How come your opening seperate tabs per step?

Comment: please explain. i don't understand your question

Comment: "i want customer to redirect to 2nd tab of the process step"?

Comment: What do you mean by tab?

Comment: I added my html markup, i want when ajax response success redirect to the 2nd tab directly now i am able reload the page but want to redirect to 2nd tab

Comment: no, i am using the default steps with tabs that comes with the theme